# Translation of "select local file(s)"

Tags: traduction, pluriel, informatique

What's the translation of "select local file(s)" in French allowing singular/plural?

- Singular: *Choisir un fichier local*
- Plural: *Choisir les fichiers locaux*

How would one combine above allowing for singular+plural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

> Choisir/sélectionner le ou les fichiers locaux
>
> Choisir/sélectionner un ou plusieurs fichiers locaux
>
> Choisir/sélectionner un fichier local ou plus
>
> Choisir/sélectionner au moins un fichier local

Comment: Why not "Sélectionner des fichiers locaux"?

Comment: @vc En excluant le singulier, il me semble que ça ne répond pas à la question.